# Typescript generics strange behaviour

Tags: typescript

```
export function resize<T extends File | Blob>(input: T, w: number, h: number): Promise<T> {
  return Promise.resolve(new File([new Blob()], 'test.jpg'))
}
```

Error:

> (48, 3) TS2322:Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>     Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Can't understand why?

Comment: Never ts'd before, but shouldn't it be `Promise<File>.resolve`?

Comment: Thanks, it works like this
return Promise.resolve(new File([new Blob()], 'test.jpg')) as Promise<T>
but I still don't get it

Comment: Gah, I just don't know enough of typescript generics (and the docs, after a quick squizz, don't have enough info--they don't even cover that `extends File | Blob` syntax, which is making my head scratch). I'm kinda shocked that `as Promise<T>` *works*.  What's up with that, [Anders?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) I'd think you would *have* to use `Promise<File>.resolve` and that `as Promise<File>` would result in a null value being returned... You sure about this?

Comment: Do you actually intend the output of `resize()` to be a promise of the *same* type as `input`, or is it always just a `File`?  If you are creating a new `File`, then you don't need generics at all; just declare the function as `resize(input: Blob, w: number, h: number): Promise<File>` (note that `File` is a subclass of `Blob`, so `File | Blob` is just `Blob`.

Comment: Same as input! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The point is your generic argument `T` is a class which **inherits** from `File` or `Blob`. And what you are returning is just a plain `Promise<File>`. Which is obviously not assignable to the inherited type. I'm not sure what exactly is the `input` argument and how it affects the output, but the return type should definitely be `Promise<File>`:

```
export function resize<T extends File | Blob>(input: T, w: number, h: number): Promise<File> {
  return Promise.resolve(new File([new Blob()], 'test.jpg'))
}
```

Comment: The point is I need to return either File or Blob depending on the input type

This worked for me, but this looks strange
`       if (isFile(input)) {
         const f = new File([blob], input.name)
            resolve(f as T)

          } else if (isBlob(input)) {
            resolve(blob as T)

          }`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but this looks strange

```
if (isFile(input)) {
    const f = new File([blob], input.name)
    resolve(f as T)
} else if (isBlob(input)) {
    resolve(blob as T)
}
```

from:

```
export
function resize<T extends Blob | File>(input: T, width: number, height: number): Promise<T> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const image = new Image()

        image.onload = () => {

            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.width = width
            canvas.height = height

            pica.resize(image, canvas)
                .then((result) => pica.toBlob(result, input.type, 85))
                .then((blob: Blob) => {

                    if (isFile(input)) {
                      const f = new File([blob], input.name)
                      resolve(f as T)

                    } else if (isBlob(input)) {
                      resolve(blob as T)

                    }
                })
                .catch(err => reject(err))
        }

        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(input)

    })
}
```

Comment: You still can't return a `Promise<T>` safely.  What if `T` is a subclass of `File`?  You cannot return the same type.  What you probably want is just an overloaded function declaration, one which takes a `File` and returns a `File`, and one which takes a `Blob` and returns a `Blob`.  The generics aren't helping you.

Comment: Thanks jcalz, I think you are right and overloaded function would be a better approach here